# Calling Python File Stored In Server

Tags: php, python, mysql, python-requests

i was wondering. I am right now building endpoints for my mobile app to interact (fetch and modify) with PHP. So for example, if i want to update my mysql database for probably fetching datas, i would just call like https://123.456.7.89/folder/anything.php where i my php files would return JSON encoded object. I wonder how can i achieve this in python? would placing a python file (.py) and calling it from URL does it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you need to use [simpleHTTP](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html). You can connect to that python based webserver and run your command.